# Site Stats - design is broken, link isn't working and should Ask Patents even have them?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, statistics

The site stats on the front page look like they're broken:

[image]

Also, both links (to Area 51 and Stack Exchange) don't work, presumably because of the special status.

**Normally, these statistics are only shown for sites which are still in beta. Should they even be shown on Ask Patents at all?**

For reference, here is how a [normal site stats](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) block looks like:

[image]

Right now, all Beta sites seem to have this problem, as noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315711/295232).

Comment: There is already a bug report for the links, but developer time ... money ... nobody cares enough to fix it. I got downvoted to hell when I tried bringing it up on the main meta.

Comment: This is half fixed. The formatting has been updated for all beta sites. I'm not sure if we have a fix for the links... I'm looking into whether this box should even be here on AP. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Friday we fixed the formatting of the box. Sorry that took so long. I'm not sure why it was broken here so long before it was broken elsewhere.

That said, this box and the box about sharing the site are generally only shown on sites considered to be in Beta.

There's no reason for them to be here at all, so we've fixed the problem of the broken A51 link by... removing the two boxes entirely!

If you want to see what the stats are for the site moving forward, you can find the information with all of the other sites on the big network-wide stats page [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), where there's actually more stats than were in the sidebar.

Comment: That's always the simplest solution :)

Comment: They've come back in the redesign. I think this site's still considered a beta site.

Comment: The box has been back again, for a while: https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/406/site-stats-box-is-showing-up-again