# "Site Stats" box is showing up again

Tags: bug, design, statistics

A couple years ago, there was a [bug report](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/site-stats-design-is-broken-link-isnt-working-and-should-ask-patents-even-ha) that the "Site Stats" box on the right had broken links. The issue was fixed by removing the box entirely, since only beta sites are supposed to have it.

However, the box has since re-appeared, and is again serving the same broken links.

Can the box please be removed again?